# Remove genes duplicates with unique ENSG ID

Tags: r

I am a beginner with R. I have a tibble data.frame: it's a gene list with EntrezgeneID, GeneSymbol, Gene description and ENSG_ID.
I would like to remove genes duplicates associated with an unique ENSG ID.
For example, AKRC1 is found in duplicate in my dataframe with 2 ENSG ids including one in common with the gene AKRC2.

Initial file

[image: Initial file]

I tried to remove duplicated but the problem that I kept AKRC1 & AKRC2 with the same ENSG ID.
This is the code used :

#Determine the indices for non-duplicated genes

`non_duplicated_idx <- which(duplicated(annotation1$GeneSymbol_v85) == FALSE)`

#Return only the non-duplicated genes using indices

`annotation1 <- annotation1 [non_duplicated_idx, ]`

The duplicated genes are removed, but here for example,  AKRC1 is kept with the ENSG_ID than AKRC2.

After removing duplicates

[image]

Is it possible to remove duplicate with an unique ENSG_ID ?
(Here, for example, I would like to keep AKRC1 with ENSG00000187134)

Many thanks for your help,
Jessica

Comment: The bigger issue here is: why does your data contain incorrect Ensembl gene IDs in the first place? *That* is the issue that needs fixing.

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `df`, with the name of your data frame:

```
df[!duplicated(df$GeneSymbol_v85), ]
```

And to see which ones are duplicated:

```
df[duplicated(df$GeneSymbol_v85), ]
```